# How to access router states in any of the viewModels - Oracle JET

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, oracle-jet

I've defined root router in main.js and have the navigation code there itself. On of the the pages there is a list and I want to open view page from the selected list item. I'm able to get the data on the page by using $root.router.retreive() in the html page.

How do I get that value in it's corresponding viewModel?

navigation code:

```
self.gotoPage = function(data, event) 
{
   self.router.store(data.id);
   self.router.go(event.target.id);
};
```

Binding Code:

```
oj.Router.sync().then(
  function () {
    // bind your ViewModel for the content of the whole page body.
    ko.applyBindings(new RootViewModel(), document.getElementById('globalBody'));
  },
  function (error) {
    oj.Logger.error('Error in root start: ' + error.message);
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use `$module` to access any variable defined in the active viewModel. 
Example: `$module.router.retreive()` to be used in the HTML binding.

If you are looking for the value in the ViewModel, you can extend `router.moduleConfig` and pass the context as `moduleParams`.

Or you can use `ko.dataFor` to pick up data from the binding context using HTML selectors.

As per comments...

```
setup: function(routerParent) {
    var router, latestState;
    if (routerParent == undefined) {
        router = oj.Router.rootInstance;
    } else {
        if (routerParent.getChildRouter(routerParent.currentState().id)) {
            routerParent.getChildRouter(routerParent.currentState().id).dispose();
        }
        router = routerParent.createChildRouter(routerParent.currentState().id);
    }
    router.configure(function(stateId) {
        if (stateId) {
            latestState = stateId;
            return new oj.RouterState(stateId);
        }
    });
    oj.Router.sync().then(function(value) {
        //console.info("Calling Router Sync: Result = " + value);
    }, function(reason) {
        console.info("Calling Router Sync: Result = " + reason);
    });
    return $.extend(router, { latestState: latestState });
},
```

Comment: Hey, thanks, it worked. Just one doubt, when i pass data in module.config like 
`return $.extend({},
              self.pageRouter.moduleConfig,
                                {name: pageRouter.moduleConfig.name(),params:{'objectId': self.router.retrieve()}});`

Where pageRouter is a grandChild of router and id is stored in router itself.

Only the parameter is being passed on the page which is giving this error - **TypeError: params.valueAccessor(...).params.ojRouter is undefined**

Comment: @Roy have a look at how i am extending... this is simple setup function which I call in call in any viewModel.... this was you dont have to define grandchilds :P it will  take up any state dynamically. Rest will be handled by `moduleConfig`

Comment: can you give me any eg. in a page how you call this function. I suppose this setup is defined in main.js

Comment: @DebajyotiDas Can you please help to solve this one.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43520553/swipe-to-reveal-is-not-working